# Documented examples of audience dissatisfaction and disengagement?

Tags: creative-writing

I don't know if this idea has any merit or if it's ever been done before, but I thought it would be useful resource to have: an archive dedicated to keeping track of shows/movies/games/books/whatever which, for one reason or another, burnt their audience, resulting in less interest, engagement and less positive scores from said audience.

What I hope to get from such an archive is to see what exactly a product, which was initially very successful and well received, did to annoy their audience to such an extent that they would lose a majority of their audience and goodwill. A list of examples on *what not to do* in your fiction basically, a TV Tropes for bad ideas, if you will.

Some examples that come to mind:

- Matrix (Sequels)
- Scrubs (Season 9)
- Dragonball (GT)
- Star Wars (Prequels and... midichlorians)

I'm looking specifically for things that were done wrong *within* the product. An unwanted plot point, a badly received new character or change to a popular existing character, the introduction of an unpopular concept, plot holes, what have you. Things that were done wrong within the product.

Is there a website dedicated to something like this? Where could I find such examples?

Comment: TV Tropes has a couple of articles dedicated to things like this: "They Changed It, Now It Sucks" is the one that immediately springs to mind.

Comment: Google "Jump The Shark".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this feels like shopping for a website.

Comment: It's much rare to have a franchise that has an audience actively engaged after a number of installments.